# How to convert bytes to CSV in python?

Tags: python, csv, byte, data-conversion

Need help in converting bytes to CSV file.I tried decoding with utf-8,latin-1,ASCII,cp1252,etc...Nothing worked.Here is the code b'\x00\x00\xd0\x05\xdf)\x93EW\x1e\x90\xec\xa8K\xe5@\x00\x00t\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009116-6631
I tried a lot of methods to decode but never got done.Please help.It is  variable length binary values.(This is just a snippet of entire code)

Comment: This doesn't look like text at all, so you can't turn it into text, whatever encoding you try. Where is that data coming from?

Comment: It is a dat file from pressure scanner software.The manual says it is converted to little endian bytes.I need to convert it into CSV file

Comment: Well, this is not text, this is binary data. Unless you know what that data is, and what format they used to store it, there is nothing you can do with it.